# Autocomplete="on" not working for some strange reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, autocomplete

Just asking, with autocomplete="on" for this feature to work on Google Chrome, do we need to have loaded the form on page load, or can it work by adding the form by jQuery to the DOM. Also does the form need to be wrapped by a form tag, or can it just be fields? Like all i have is a firstname and a lastname, and jQuery handles the ajax so there is no need for a form tag.

Answer (score 3):

The `autocomplete` HTML parameter only works inside a form that has been previously submitted. However, you could fake the submission of a form without actually submitting it as per [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462991/trigger-autocomplete-without-submitting-a-form).

Since the form has to be submitted, yes, you do need to have the fields included inside a form.

Also noteworthy is that `autocomplete` defaults to on, so there's no need to use the parameter unless you want to disable autocomplete (some sites use this to prevent the user from autocompleting email verification).

Comment: Sometime I got the form pre-filled on the site where I never gone in Chrome. What about That kind of thing ?

Comment: @F1beta, perhaps you're referring to Chrome's autofill feature: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893?hl=en