# Trigger autocomplete with ngClick without submitting the form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, autocomplete

The issue is in chrome where I have few fields in a form and want to utilize autocomplete feature of the browser. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345879/input-autocomplete-on-does-not-work-with-chrome-is-it-a-bug) I found the problem with chrome(that it save data only on form submit) and therefore as suggested by the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462991/trigger-autocomplete-without-submitting-a-form), I tried to fire the **click** event which in turn fires the **ngClick** on the same element which eventually runs into a loop.

So how do I make use of autocomplete feature while still using "ngClick"?

Comment: You can always use ready directives for autocomplete, like angucomplete.

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nofls3lLJTOYtE51wPNd?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to trigger autocomplete would be to use `ngSubmit`. However as you want to use `ngClick`, a solution like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25102791 would work. You are submitting the form from the controller. Triggering the native submit function needs to be applied through a directive as this is the recommended place to manipulate the DOM using AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this too and came across this post so I will share what I have discovered so far with my own solution, and hopefully it helps :)
I also encountered an infinite loop with my autocomplete and after many trials I discovered if I call my function differently it doesn't push the loop.

```
on-select="ctrl.updateAutoComplete"
```

I believe that will still work for your ngClick (basically I just removed the brackets here)

and then in my controller instead of using

public updateAutocomplete(query: string) {//do stuff here}

I ended up using

```
public updateAutocomplete = function(query: string) { // do stuff here }
```

it seems like kind of a brutish way of getting around it but so far it's working for me. I found it also obscures the $scope a bit which is why I am looking for a better solution. But anyways this is how I got away from the loop, I hope it helps.