# Does every browser have about:blank page?

Tags: html, cross-browser

I have a form that looks like:

```
<form id="search-form" action="about:blank" target="none">
  <input type="text" id="search-text">
  <button id="search-submit"> Go! </button>
</form>
<iframe name="none" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

While I don't want my form to update the page, yet I want autocomplete to work properly so I send a blank page to the iframe every time the form is submitted.

Will this solution work on every browser? (Or should I create a "/blank" blank page response on the server...)

Comment: What does the autocomplete require to work properly? Would it work to prevent submission of the form altogether?

Comment: You probably should go with an AJAX solution here, not an iframe.

Comment: @JoeEnos I go with ajax, but you know there's a built-in autocomplete in the browsers that just works fine with me...

Comment: @showdev I have tried that but then the browser will not remember the  input in its autocomplete.

Comment: I assume you're referring the browser's native autocomplete functionality. You may have already seen this post, but the accepted answer seems to use a method similar to yours: [Trigger autocomplete without submitting a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462991/trigger-autocomplete-without-submitting-a-form)