# How to allow only POST calls to serve Nginx static json files

Tags: nginx

HI i am trying to serve static json files from Nginx. However i want to serve these static files only via POST request and disable the GET calls.

Is there any way to do so.

[I refered to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415376/post-request-not-allowed-405-not-allowed-nginx-even-with-headers-included)  However this looks like a hack and i am looking for some more reliable solution

Answer (score 0):

Just include the following in your location block for static files:

```
limit_except POST {
    deny all;
}
```

This will send a 403 for every request not using POST as HTTP method..

BTW, there are different ways to achieve this, such as CORS, but I think it's out of scope here.