# 405 not allowed nginx, CORS? Nginx config? Or something else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, heroku, ember.js, cors

Working on an app built using Ember.js and Rails.
Authentication is being done with ember-simple-auth using Oauth2.
I am able to login to my app locally in my development environment, but as soon as I try to login on my production server (through Heroku) I start receiving a `nginx 405 not allowed` status code.

First thing I thought was maybe it is my request headers / CORS. I am using `rack-cors` gem on my rails side and configured it based directly off the readme example. Here is my [application.rb](https://github.com/datadazer/Bidtracker/blob/master/bidtracker-api/config/application.rb#L11-L28)

Researching, I found [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415376/post-request-not-allowed-405-not-allowed-nginx-even-with-headers-included) with the solution being to configure Nginx side of things, but I figured since that is being handled by heroku I wasn't really sure if that was where I need to make my changes.

Let me know if there are any other files/info that could help.

What is the best way to debug this problem?

[image]

Comment: is the route you're trying to access behind an authentication wall?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this first to rule out CORS:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Does the route work locally when you use Postman or a similar tool?

Are you requesting HTML or JSON?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'll give a shot at Postman and that allow-control-allow-origin extension and let you know how it goes

Comment: when using Postman, I got my token available, and running post to localhost:3000/token keeps giving me a 500 error "ArgumentError: Missing authorization code". I pressed Use Token before doing so.

Comment: a little more specifically I'm having issues somewhere in here https://github.com/datadazer/Bidtracker/blob/master/bidtracker-api/app/controllers/tokens_controller.rb#L25-L35
only while trying to use Postman to send a POST request. On the other hand, my local version by hitting the login button seems to work fine. Also I'm using JSON in case I didn't state that previously.