# React Js application on page refresh/reload gives error

Tags: reactjs

I have a react frontend applictaion with Rails API as backend. When I tries to register or signup or even if i click any menu links from application it redirects to clicked pages and everything works without any issue. but if i tries to reload/refresh any url it gives me 404 error. In development server everything works fine, but this issue is appearing only on production server.

Here is my react code.
app.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "./Axios";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import {
      BrowserRouter as Router,
      Route,
      Switch,
      Link,
      Redirect,
      withRouter,
} from "react-router-dom";
        
const App = () => {
      const [loggedInStatus, setLoggedInStatus] = React.useState("NOT_LOGGED_IN");
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState({});
  const history = useHistory();
  const [userName, setUserName] = React.useState("");
  const handleSuccessfulAuth = (data) => {
    handleLogin(data);
  };
const handleLogin = (data) => {
    if (data.status === "logged") {
      setLoggedInStatus("LOGGED_IN");
      setUser(data.user);
      history.push("/view-profile"); //redirect to profile if loggedin
    } else if (data.status === "created") {
      history.push("/login"); //redirect to login page if regsitration successfull
    }
  };

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid app-container">
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
                <Route path="/login">
                  <Login handleSuccessfulAuth={handleSuccessfulAuth} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/signup">
                  <Signup handleSuccessfulAuth={handleSuccessfulAuth} />
                </Route>
                 <Route path="/view-profile">
          <ProfileView job_seeker={user} />
        </Route>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/basic">
                  <Basic logged_user={user} />
                </Route>    
              </Switch>
            </div>
      );
};
        
export default App;
```

Gives me 404 error when i tries to refresh the page.

Comment: When you try to reload any page? Also what's the error you're getting

Comment: Can you post what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: Where is the method handleSuccessfulAuth defined?

Comment: Where is handleLogin defined?

Comment: @Nemanja handleSuccessfulAuth is working fine. no issue with it. if i tries to refresh page it gives 404 error.

Comment: @Tushar Shahi please see updated code

Comment: Can you add in the question detail what is the flow causing the error. Is it only login or whenever you enter website.

Comment: Where your app is deployed?

Comment: @Tushar Shahi  this issue causes in every pages except landing page. if i click any menus it redirects to everypage suceesfully .but if i tries to reload/refresh the same page which i clicked from menu,  it gives me error

Comment: @RS SANI AHMED deployed in linode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

for Nginx:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

According to Linode:

> All NGINX configuration files are located in the /etc/nginx/ directory. The primary configuration file is /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

If you don't find this file on this path, please create one.

**Old Answer:** (for Apache Servers)

Yes this happens on production servers. You need to add `.htaccess` file in your React directory with that source code into it.

The content of `.htaccess` file would be as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

You can change this as per requirement but this handles almost all normal scenarios.

Comment: Which folder am I supposed to put this file into?

Comment: Hosted in Linode nginx server

Comment: I think the above configuration will work with Apache Server, not in Nginx

Comment: ah yes you are right. please see my updated answer.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Any idea about 405 error? now i'm getting this error when i tries to login. before it was working.

Comment: Yes, you can follow the 1st Answer to this stackoverflow question as a workaround, I am afraid, I may not be able to explain it further. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415376/post-request-not-allowed-405-not-allowed-nginx-even-with-headers-included