# Why is my Axios POST Request Returning a 405 Error in Production?

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, axios, cors

I have a React website with a simple contact (which you can find [here](https://tales-from-the-closet.herokuapp.com/contact)) form that's powered by Nodemailer and an Express backend. The form sends an email as expected when testing locally. But after deploying to Heroku I'm getting a `405` error in Production whenever I submit the form.

[image]

Here are the relevant parts of my initial configuration:

**server/index.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
let app = express();

dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());
app.options('*', cors());

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to the backend!')
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));
});

// have Node serve the files for our built React app
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build')));

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
  name: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.MAIL_USER,
    pass: process.env.MAIL_PASS
  },
  tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
  logger: true
});

transporter.verify((error, success) => {
  console.log(error ? error : 'Server is ready to take our messages');
});

app.post('/api', cors(), (req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.data.name,
        email = req.body.data.email,
        message = req.body.data.message,
        mail = {
          from: name + ' <' + email + '>',
          to: process.env.MAIL_TO,
          subject: 'Contact Form Submission',
          text: message
        };

  transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
    res.json({ status: err ? 'fail' : 'success' });
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001
app.listen(PORT, () => console.info(`server has started on ${PORT}`))
```

**Submit Handler in my Contact Form Component:**

```
  const submitRequest = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = { name, email, message };
    axios.post('/api', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data.status === 'success') {
          setName('');
          setEmail('');
          setMessage('');
          setSubmitted(true);
        } else if (response.data.status === 'fail') {
          // do something
        }
        return response;
      });
  };
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

**static.json**

```
{
  "root": "client/build/",
  "clean_urls": false,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

***Operating under the assumption that this is a CORS issue, here's what I've tried:***

1. Adding `app.use(cors())` to Express backend in `server/index.js` - I wasn't sure this was necessary given that I'm already passing in `cors()` when defining my `/api` route, but I nonetheless tried it
2. Adding Additional request headers `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to my axios POST request -- ie:

```
axios.post('/api', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data
})
```

But neither of these changes fixed the problem. **Is there something else I should be adding to the request header of my axios POST request and/or to my `server/index.js` file? Could my `.htaccess` file be the culprit? Or is it something else entirely?** Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [POST request not allowed - 405 Not Allowed - nginx, even with headers included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415376/post-request-not-allowed-405-not-allowed-nginx-even-with-headers-included)

Comment: Thanks, there are some useful pointers...but where do I find/how do I edit the nginx.config.erb file?

Answer (score 0):

The create-react-app buildpack uses the heroku/static buildpack which in turn uses a nginx web server. Unfortunately nginx does not allow POST calls from static pages.

Try using a GET request instead.

Comment: Since it's a contact form, a GET request isn't possible. I have to make a POST request. Is there no workaround for this?

Comment: Try writing to their support or avoid hosting on heroku would be my guess @asw1984

Comment: do you know where I can find/how I can edit the nginx.config.erg file?