# Autocomplete="on" not working in chrome, on Angular ng-submit

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, post, autocomplete, submit

I am submitting a angular form using ng-submit. This is the code which I am working on.

```
      <form class="awesome-form" id="loginForm" name="loginForm" ng-submit="submit();" novalidate>
      <div class="input-group">

      <input id="loginEmailAddress" name="loginEmailAddress"
            ng-model="login.loginId" 
            ng-pattern="/^[_a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/"
            ng-keyup = "checkType($event,'login-label');"
            required="" type="text" autocomplete="on">
       <label id="login-label">Email</label>
       </div>
       <span class="icon-close" ng-show="!loginForm.loginEmailAddress.$error.required"
        ng-click="clear()"></span>
       </div>

       /*some other form elements come here*/

       <button class="login-button-blue" 
        ng-disabled="!(loginForm.loginEmailAddress.$valid  && loginForm.loginPassword.$valid)" type="submit">SIGN IN</button>

        </form>
```

The submit method is calling a service which in turn sends a http post request.

```
        $scope.submit = function() {
                          SampleService.sampleMethod(angular.toJson(request)).then(function(successData){
            /**do something**/
                  }
        }
```

The sampleservice is as follows:

```
     app.service('SampleService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
          this.sampleMethod= function (request) {
              var deferred = $q.defer();
              $http.post("url", request).success(function (data, status,   headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
             }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               deferred.reject(data);
             });
             return deferred.promise;
          };
     }]);
```

After successful submission of my form, I expect the browser's native autocomplete feature to work. The email address is to be autocompleted when I type in the next time.

It works successful in firefox, but not in chrome. I tried several methods mentioned in other stack overflow questions. But the solutions proved useless.

([Trigger autocomplete without submitting a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462991/trigger-autocomplete-without-submitting-a-form))

A fiddle has been given in the solution for that question that it worked in all the browsers(http://jsfiddle.net/6cve0z98/). But it was also not working for me.

1. I am using chrome version 41.0.2272.118.
2. A post method is used.

Is it a problem with the browser itself or am I doing something wrong? Help me with the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue, with ng-submit and from what I tried, and this also happens in Opera or Safari. Did not manage to find a solution