# Chome autofill: Is there a limit to the number of fields for it to work?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, forms

I have two forms that are submitted using Ajax, so I used the iframe hack to make autofill work (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29885896/1964031). Only in one of those forms it works and the only difference seems to be the amount of inputs. One has around 20, while the other has ~100.

In fact, I opened the form that isn't working, removed a lot of it's fields and tried again. It worked.

Is there a certain amount of fields for which chrome's autofill stops working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a maximum of 1k per web page of auto filled data that can be stored. I think it's independent of the number of fields. It's the total autofill data that matters.

Looking at the chrome code

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/components/autofill/core/browser/webdata/autofill_table.cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=392

Shows the constant (kMaxDataLength) set to 1024 characters.

Comment: Thanks Miguel! I've been searching for an answer everywhere. It seems that Firefox has a bigger limit. I did the same tests with it and had no problem with autofill